Modification for use of dnaseq package
I need to write a dna sequence in my work so I was looking for a package or a way to achieve that. I found the package dnaseq but it seemed to me that I didn't have everything I needed, then I found this answer from Steven B. Segletes that seemed quite complete to me, but I noticed that, for example, when I use a red colorbox, the text inside the box is not visble well, so I would like to change the color of the text as well. I let the same minimal work suggested in the original answer
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dnaseq}
\makeatletter
\def\@DNA#1{%
    %% insert a space after \DNAblock bases
    \ifnum\count@=\DNAblock\count@=0\ %
    \advance\@tempcnta by 1\fi
    \def\@DNA@cmp{#1}%
    %% check for end of sequence or color shift
    \ifx\@DNA@cmp\@DNA@end
    \let\next\egroup
    \else
    \ifx\@DNA@cmp\@DNA@color
    \let\next\@DNA@setcolor
    \else
    \advance\count@ by 1
    \advance\@tempcntb by 1
    %% line break after calculated number of blocks
    \ifnum\@tempcnta=\blocks \\
    \hskip\z@\phantom{\DNAreserve}\llap {\the\@tempcntb}\ %
    \@tempcnta=0
    \fi
    \makebox[\boxwidth]{\struty\@DNA@thecolor{#1}}%
    \penalty0\let\next\@DNA
    \fi
    \fi
    \next
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\boxwidth{1.1ex}

\begin{document}
    \DNA!
    '{\textbf} TAATACGACTCACTATAGGG 
    '{\colorbox{red}}AACGCTAGTC
    '{\color{red}} ATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTA GTCATGCATC 
    '{\textit} GTATGTAACG 
    '{\textcolor{red}} CTAGTCATGC 
    '{\scriptsize\rmfamily} ATCGTATGTA 
    '{} ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGT
    CATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACG
    CTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATG 
    !
\end{document}


(Result, added by MS-SPO)
My first and only idea was to add a new argument like this
\makeatletter
\def\@DNA#1{%
    %% insert a space after \DNAblock bases
    \ifnum\count@=\DNAblock\count@=0\ %
    \advance\@tempcnta by 1\fi
    \def\@DNA@cmp{#1}%
    %% check for end of sequence or color shift
    \ifx\@DNA@cmp\@DNA@end
    \let\next\egroup
    \else
    \ifx\@DNA@cmp\@DNA@color
    \let\next\@DNA@setcolor
    \else
    \advance\count@ by 1
    \advance\@tempcntb by 1
    %% line break after calculated number of blocks
    \ifnum\@tempcnta=\blocks \\
    \hskip\z@\phantom{\DNAreserve}\llap {\the\@tempcntb}\ %
    \@tempcnta=0
    \fi
    \makebox[\boxwidth]{\struty\@DNA@thecolor{\color{red}#1}}%
    \penalty0\let\next\@DNA
    \fi
    \fi
    \next
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\boxwidth{1.1ex}

Of course, I should define a new argument to change the color red for any other color, but I don't know how to do it directly. By now, my best "result" was changing the color letter by letter, something like '{\colorbox{red}}{\color{white}A}{\color{white}A}{\color{white}C}CGCTAGTC, but this is very tedious, especially if it involves very long sequences. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance :D

The problem is where \struty is placed, which should be next to #1.
Also the package defines \struty in a very cumbersome and slow way, so I also remove that part from the main command (leaving it untouched for the rest) and define \DNA@strut.
You also don't need \boxwidth.
I'd avoid pure colors, with xcolor it's easy.
Note how to color the text inside a background color: first the text color, then the background.
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dnaseq}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt} % for distinctive boldface

\makeatletter

% remove the awkward definition of `\struty`
\def\DNA#1{%
   \def\@DNA@end{#1}\bgroup\ttfamily\DNAc@lcline
   %% dnabase per line counter
   \count@=0
   %% block counter
   \@tempcnta=0
   %% total dnabase counter
   \@tempcntb=0
   \fboxrule=0pt \fboxsep=0pt
   \noindent\phantom{\DNAreserve}\llap{1}\ %
   \@DNA
}
% a better strut
\def\DNA@strut{%
  \vrule height \dimeval{\fontcharht\font`I+2pt} depth 1pt width 0pt
}

% fix Steven's code
\def\@DNA#1{%
    %% insert a space after \DNAblock bases
    \ifnum\count@=\DNAblock\count@=0\ %
    \advance\@tempcnta by 1\fi
    \def\@DNA@cmp{#1}%
    %% check for end of sequence or color shift
    \ifx\@DNA@cmp\@DNA@end
    \let\next\egroup
    \else
    \ifx\@DNA@cmp\@DNA@color
    \let\next\@DNA@setcolor
    \else
    \advance\count@ by 1
    \advance\@tempcntb by 1
    %% line break after calculated number of blocks
    \ifnum\@tempcnta=\blocks \\
    \hskip\z@\phantom{\DNAreserve}\llap{\the\@tempcntb}\ %
    \@tempcnta=0
    \fi
    \makebox[0.5em]{\@DNA@thecolor{\DNA@strut#1}}% <--- here the changes
    \penalty0\let\next\@DNA
    \fi
    \fi
    \next
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\DNA!
  '{\textbf} TAATACGACTCACTATAGGG 
  '{\colorbox{red!60}}AACGCTAGTC
  '{\color{white}\colorbox{red!69}} TGTAACGCTA
  '{} GTCATGCATC 
  '{\color{red!60}} ATGCATCGTA
  '{\textit} GTATGTAACG 
  '{\textcolor{red!60}} CTAGTCATGC 
  '{\scriptsize\rmfamily} ATCGTATGTA 
  '{} ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGT
  CATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACG
  CTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATG 
!

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your answer, but I'm not sure if the problem with coloring text inside a box is solved. I'm trying to get a fragment of the sequence inside a colorbox and also coloring the text inside the box, something like '{\colorbox{red!60}\color{white}}AACGCTAGTCAAAA. I know that I can use "softer" colors, but I'd would like to be able to applied this when be necessary. Thanks for your help

@MichaelRosalesVilca  Use '{\color{white}\colorbox{red!60}}, I updated the answer.

Wow, thank you for your patience. It looks so good :D

Here is a different approach, using TikZ, which gives you a wide range of control over colors etc.
Objective:

Basic idea
You split your groups into sequences like this:
    \tikz{\node {TAATACGACT};} 
    \tikz{\node {CACTATAGGG};} 
    \tikz{\node[bx1] {AACGCTAGTC};}
    \tikz{\node[bx2] {ATGCATCGTA};}

where:

\tikz{} is a shortcut to create a tikzpicture environment
\node {}; creates a node, where you put text inside the backets
[bx2] is an option to your node, which you define the way you want
and as you can see below its effect is much like typing other LaTeX commands

Completing that code gives 80 % of your first line in the coloration you want.
Details - styles
In the beginning you define text and color styles the way you need:
% ~~~ defining color-styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\tikzset{
    fnt/.style={font={\ttfamily}},
    fnti/.style={font={\itshape\ttfamily}},
    nrml/.style={fnt,color=black},
    boxa/.style={fnt,color=black,fill=red!30!orange!40},
    boxb/.style={fnt,color=red},
    boxc/.style={fnti,color=black},
    boxd/.style={fnt,color=blue,fill=yellow!50},
}


fnt and fnti take care of font, size, italics and so on (they are kind of duplicate because of font={})
the others just define color schemes AND reuse either of fnt or fnti (it's a bit like with CSS)
you can use more memorable names than boxa etc.
for the colors you can use e.g. the mixing approach from TikZ (as shown), or package xcolor etc.; make your choice

Details - shortcuts
Let's encapsulate aboves \tikz{} calls, taking care of the styles, too. Please note that you can't use box1, box2 etc. as names for new commands.
% ~~~ simplifying typing ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\nrml[1]{\tikz{\node[nrml] {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxa[1]{\tikz{\node[boxa] {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxb[1]{\tikz{\node[boxb] {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxc[1]{\tikz{\node[boxc] {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxd[1]{\tikz{\node[boxd] {#1};}}

Now your first line is sth like this; the grouping gives at least me some kind of self-control (it's harder to introduce errors, thouogh possible):
    \nrml {TAATACGACT}
    \nrml {CACTATAGGG}
    \boxa {AACGCTAGTC}
    \boxb {ATGCATCGTA}
    \boxb {TGTAACGCTA}

Details - counting
No big deal:

introduce a new counter
initialize it
output it via \tikz{}, care for the correct format, increment it
put \cnt before you line of sequences
for other lengths just change Nsteps and pass longer or shorter text to the shortcuts

% ~~~ caring for the counts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcounter{N}
\def\Nsteps{50}     % stepsize
\setcounter{N}{1}   % initialized

\newcommand\cnt[0]{\tikz{\node[text width=8mm,anchor=east,align=flush right] {\number\value{N}\addtocounter{N}{\Nsteps}};}}

Full code
Now that you can have anything you want I'd go with these changes:

use ttfamily, which avoids variable length of sequences
better stay with colors rather than harder to see font changes for sequence 81
keep the calls simple enough; e.g. the 5 calls to \nrml{} could also be assigned to a more complciated \newcommand like with 5 parameters \norm{}{}{}{}{}, which is a matter of convenience, preference, refactoring

For a more advanced approach you certainly can introduce some kind of autosplitting, which makes code more complciated and sensitive to errors.

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ defining color-styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\tikzset{
    fnt/.style={font={\ttfamily}},
    fnti/.style={font={\itshape\ttfamily}},
    nrml/.style={fnt,color=black},
    boxa/.style={fnt,color=black,fill=red!30!orange!40},
    boxb/.style={fnt,color=red},
    boxc/.style={fnti,color=black},
    boxd/.style={fnt,color=blue,fill=yellow!50},
}

% ~~~ simplifying typing ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\nrml[1]{\tikz{\node[nrml] {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxa[1]{\tikz{\node[boxa] {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxb[1]{\tikz{\node[boxb] {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxc[1]{\tikz{\node[boxc] {#1};}}
\newcommand\boxd[1]{\tikz{\node[boxd] {#1};}}

% ~~~ caring for the counts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcounter{N}
\def\Nsteps{50}     % stepsize
\setcounter{N}{1}   % initialized

\newcommand\cnt[0]{\tikz{\node[text width=8mm,anchor=east,align=flush right] {\number\value{N}\addtocounter{N}{\Nsteps}};}}


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
    \cnt
    \nrml {TAATACGACT}
    \nrml {CACTATAGGG}
    \boxa {AACGCTAGTC}
    \boxb {ATGCATCGTA}
    \boxb {TGTAACGCTA}

    \cnt
    \boxb {GTCATGCATC}
    \boxc {GTATGTAACG}
    \boxb {CTAGTCATGC}
    \boxd {ATCGTATGTA}
    \nrml {ACGCTAGTCA}
    
    \cnt
    \nrml {TGCATCGTAT}
    \nrml {GTAACGCTAG}
    \nrml {TCATGCATCG}
    \nrml {TATGTAACGC}
    \nrml {TAGTCAGCAx}

\end{document}

